# Handlers in Android Programming

Tags: android, handlers

I have got to know that the Handlers are basically used to Run the Small Section of Code and etc...

But I didn't got the exact scenerio about when particularly It is Ideal to use the Handlers!

Any Help???

Thanks,
david

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handlers are used for updating the UI from other (non-UI) threads.

For example, you can declare a Handler on your Activity class:

```
Handler h = new Handler();
```

Then you have some other tasks on different thread that wants to update some UI (progress bar,  status message, etc). This will crash:

```
progressBar.setProgress(50);
```

Instead, call this:

```
h.post(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
         progressBar.setProgress(50);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the Help yuku, I appreciate your effort for me. I finally got it this time indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a newbie myself but I'll give a newbie example since I recently learned this, I'm sure there are many more.

You have to use a `Handler` when you want to update the main UI when you are doing something in another thread.  For example in my case I used it in image slideshow code that runs in a `TimerTask`. You cannot update the main UI `ImageView` with the next image from within the `TimerTask` because it's in a different thread. So you have to use a `Handler` or you get an error.

This is just one example. I hope this helps.